# Importing database data into Joomla

Tags: python, database, api, content-management-system, joomla

How to import data from a database to Joomla CMS?

I have a database with lots of data I want to use in my new website. An ideal solution for me would be a Python/Perl/PHP API that would know how to do Joomla' basic routines:

1. adding/removing a section/category/material/menu/module;
2. changing properties of existing entities

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following extensions:

1. [Bulk Import](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-&-conversion/data-import-&-export/7243/details)
2. [CSV Import](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-&-conversion/extensions-migration/4247/details)

If that doesn't work for you, maybe take a look at the [Joomla API](http://api.joomla.org/)